# Where can I find the register order 'G' sends in GDB

Tags: gdb, gdbserver

When the gdb-remote sends a 'g' server sends back a dump with all register value. 
Q: Where can I find the register order. What I mean is the order eax, ebx, ecx, edx or rax, rbx, rdx etc .. map to the dump. The spec does have a link but when I click it, it just keeps looping back. Same thing happened with IE and Chrome so gave it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean where in gdb sources, then this order is now defined by xml files in gdb/features directory. Like [32bit-core.xml](https://sourceware.org/git/gitweb.cgi?p=binutils-gdb.git;a=blob_plain;f=gdb/features/i386/32bit-core.xml;hb=HEAD), for example.

If this is what you are looking for, you will probably get better answer (to this and similar questions) on one of [GDB mailing lists](https://www.sourceware.org/gdb/mailing-lists/).

Comment: 1000 thanks to you this is exactly what I wanted and I will assume same order holds good for 64 bit too.... Thanks also for pointing me to the right list.

Comment: What is the logic in changing the order between 32 and 64 bit registers? 32 bit: eax, ecx, edx, ebx, esp, ebp, esi, edi ... whereas 64bit goes: rax, rbx, rcx, rdx, rsi, rdi, rbp, rsp ... That means we have to map it differently depending on 32/64 bit width. Just wondering why did they do it. The only reason I can think is 32  bit existed for a long time and then came 64 bit and they realized the mistakes in the 32 bit order and went for a better order in 64. Is that right?

Comment: Kinda sorta.  The 32bit processors numbered the registers internally as eax/ecx/edx/ebx and so on. The 64bit processors __may__ have been designed with a more _natural_ numbering order.  No idea on specifics, but I do know the 32bit numbering is wonky, gave me headaches when designing a disassembler.